# Local Storage in Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am new to Shopify App Development and want to store some data which we generate after interacting with shopify API data. Is it possible to store data locally.

Comment: Have you tried asking shopify?

Comment: Yeah but didn't get any response over there,so gave a try here.

Comment: Define locally.

Answer (score 0):

If by "locally" you mean to store data into the Shopify database itself, you can use Metafields that are attached to entities in Shopify. See [Shopify Metafield API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield)

But in the other hand, if by "locally" you mean you want to store data you get and process from the Shopify API, you can simply store it in your own database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming locally means => Storing into your own server where API is hosted.

If you want to add or update other than in-build content which are provided in shopify. You will have to use **shopify ScriptTag**.

Ref. https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/online_store/scripttag#index

You could directly modify the way their website behaves. You could add image carousels to their home page that feature certain products. You could integrate a custom live chat feature that helps the store owner and their staff interact with their site visitors and potential customers. You could even build a popup widget that exchanges a discount code for the visitors email address.